# Get unique device id for amazon echo

Tags: alexa-voice-service, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I am writing a custom skill for the amazon echo and I need to get a unique device id so I can register then product to my service. Everything I read says that you cannot get the id from the device. Has amazon changed this?  Is there a work around to get a device id?

Comment: This is the same I think as this question. And also refers to an update that provides a solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351019/get-unique-device-id-for-every-amazon-echo-devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get a unique device ID. All you can do is get a unique User ID. There is no known workaround.

Answer (score 7):

This week Amazon added the Device ID (unique) to the LaunchRequest JSON payload in Alexa Skills.

```
{
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "string",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "string"
    },
  },
  "context": {
      "device": {
        "deviceId": "string",     
      },
  "request": {}
}
```

You can use the context->device->deviceId string to uniquely identify the device from which the request came.

Read more @ https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#request-body-syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for how to get **Alexa Device ID**?

Use the below snippet, It will work like a charm.

```
device_id = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.device.device_id
```

I hope this helps you.