# Get unique device id for every amazon echo devices

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I need to make a Custom Skill for the Alexa Skills Kit, which should be one echo device in every room. I need to get the device_id for every echo device. 
I heard this isn't possible, but maybe it changed, or if not is there any other way around.

Comment: https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-node-device-address-api

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Could you finally solve it? Is it possible to get a unique deviceId nowadays? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it now!
[context:System:device:deviceId](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/device-address-api#get-the-consent-token-and-device-id)

As far as I can tell it only works on real devices. So if you are testing in the developer's Skills Manager you don't get the field, but when used with a real Alexa device, it works.

Comment: If it is real what you're saying, it seems like a great opportunity. Thanks a lot for the respond

Comment: Please keep in mind that 'context:System:device:deviceId' changes when a user turns off and re-enable Alexa skill.

Comment: It looks like 'deviceId' is specific to each skill, i.e. different skills see different 'deviceId's. I tried to assign my devices to certain rooms in a database with one skill and then get this information in another skill--and failed. The idea was to put each device in each room and have different responses depending on which room they are in. Is it at all possible to get a permanent unique ID of the Echo device (like MAC address)?

Comment: Discovered that too. What I did was to create an auto registration, so that the first time an ID is encountered it gets put into my DB as unauthorized. And then I validate by hand. I supposed you could voice validate too with a conversation. 
A:"New device detected, voice validate now" 
H:"Picard 1 alpha 0 0 0 1" 
A:"Voice validation accepted, where is this device?"
H:"Billiard Room"
A:"OK"

Comment: @PavelAnni You probably have already seen it, but check out Alexa for Business if not. They have a room API.

Answer (score 3):

This is not yet possible, but you can get the `'userId'` from `event.session.user.userId`.