# I have a Amazon's Echo Dot, and I have several Echo devices too, i want to differentiate them

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

​I'm using Amazon's Echo Dot, and I have several Echo devices. I want to identity that, from which echo dot invokes a request, is it possible to find whether which, echo dot makes request, with any unique identity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get unique device id for every amazon echo devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351019/get-unique-device-id-for-every-amazon-echo-devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In the Alexa Skill Kit Documentation is a chapter about Request and Response JSON Reference. If you look [here](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#system-object).

Look for the device object in your request. It includes an unique device-ID.

```
var yourDeviceID = this.event.context.System.device.deviceId;
```

Comment: works charm for my case its working with this minor change, Thanks Man 
    var yourDeviceID = event.context.System.device.deviceId;