# When do device ID's reset for alexa skills and can the device IDs be reliably used?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am aware you can retrieve a **unique ID** for the device a custom Alexa skill was requested from via `context.System.device.deviceId`, however, I've noticed the *ID for a given device changes time to time* which leads me to a couple questions:

1. When does it reset?
2. Can this in someway be reliably used to always identify which device a request was made from? i.e. is there a work-around?

I want to be able to make room specific responses for a property without the need for the user to specify the room through identifying a given device.

Thanks

Comment: skill enabled/disabled on users Alexa account side -> RESET
echo turned off/on at mains ->No RESET
echo unregistered/registered with Alexa account -> RESET

Answer (score 0):

I found these for you:

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/168606/each-alexa-skill-have-different-device-id.html

[Get unique device id for every amazon echo devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351019/get-unique-device-id-for-every-amazon-echo-devices)

Looks like every time a skill is disabled and then re-enabled on an account, it changes the device ID. Apparently device ID's are different for eaceh skill too.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I read, the deviceId is only unique by the skill. So if you have 2 skills on one device, each has its own deviceId (ironic, right?). The deviceId stays the same for one skill, until you remove and add the skill again. Otherwise you should be good.